# ASP Net Text box with Google like dropdown search values

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, dropdownbox

I am looking for a `textbox` in C# which should work like dropdown search values when I type anything in the textbox. Those values will come from calling a method.. and I Should be able to select any of the values.
Do i need to use the asp dropdownlist or is there any other sample code available which could help me.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into jQuery autocomplete feature.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Link only answers are generally discouraged in case the resource is deleted. Having said that questions this broad are also discouraged as there are many solutions to the OP's question. But the AutoComplete was my first thought too!

Comment: yes this is wt i am looking for where can i get complete source code of this .. javascript and css

Comment: You can either use the download link on the page or get the nuget package through visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

The ajax control toolkit provides Autocomplete extender to do just that. The control calls a method, which you specify, asynchronously and get all the values to be shown as an option. I would imagine these values would be retrieved when the page loads and will not be session specific so can be stored in a cache for faster retrieval.

http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx